# AWS Application Load Balancer transforms all headers to lower case

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, http-headers, amazon-elb

I've a REST API application running in two EC2 instance and was using AWS Classic Load Balancer for a long time. The clients of REST API rely on the response headers (e.g. such as `Location`).

I know that HTTP headers are case-insensitive by definition, however (unfortunately) some clients are ignoring this and checking the headers in a case-sensitive way (e.g. they expect `Location` to start with upper case).

Recently I've changed to AWS Application Load Balancer and now I see that it transforms all response headers to lower case, as a result clients are failing to handle the response properly.

I've couple of questions here.

1. Is it expected behavior of Application Load Balancer?
2. Is there a way to configure it to return headers as they have been built by the application?

Comment: "Recently I've changed to AWS Application Load Balancer and now I see that it transforms all response headers to lower case, as a result clients are failing to handle the response properly." This statement of yours helped me , I thought the load balancer was removing my headers but turned out they were making them lowercase...thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is an expected function of the ALB because [HTTP/2 lowercases all headers](https://evertpot.com/http-2-finalized/) and ALBs [support HTTP/2](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-application-load-balancer/). Unfortunately you can't modify how the headers are manipulated by the ALB.

**Update**: See the comments below. My statement that the ALB lowercases the request headers due to its support for HTTP/2 may not be accurate.

Comment: Testing indicates that this answer is partially incorrect or incomplete.    When the request is being handled in HTTP/2 mode, ALB does indeed appear to coerce the headers to lowercase -- as it must -- but when the client isn't HTTP/2 capable, this coercion **does not** appear to happen... so it's not happening merely *because ALB supports* HTTP/2, but rather *because the client is using* HTTP/2.  If a client is seeing lowercase headers, then it would appear that is necessarily the case that the client must be speaking HTTP/2 to the ALB... which means the client is broken if lowercase fails.

Comment: Does that indicate if the the REST clients are HTTP/1 then vtor's case-sensitive clients will function as expected?

Comment: It seems to indicate that, yes... so either the rest clients are HTTP/2 and have broken header interpretation, or the nature of the problem has been misidentified.

Comment: Thanks for looking so deep into it.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot and jbird Thanks for the answers. The client indeed handles the headers in a wrong way (custom checks, etc) and they use HTTP2.

Answer (score 9):

This was causing our broken clients to fail when we switched from TCP ELB to HTTPS ELB.

While we fix our clients, we temporarily disabled the new ELB HTTP/2 support, which comes enabled by default.

[image: Disable HTTP/2 in the load balancer attributes]