# AWS Application Load Balancer with HTTP2

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, http2

I have a RESTful app deployed on a number of EC2 instances sitting behind a Load Balancer.
Authentication is handled in part by a custom request header called "X-App-Key".

I have just migrated my classic Load Balancers to Application Load Balancers and I'm starting to experience intermittent issues where some valid requests (via testing with CURL) are failing authentication for some users. It looks like the custom request header is only intermittently being passed through. Using apache bench approx 100 of 500 requests failed.
If I test with a classic Load Balancer all 500 succeed.

I looked into this a bit more and found that the users who this is failing for are using a slightly newer version of CURL and specifically the requests coming from these users are using HTTP2. If I add "--http1.1" to the CURL request they all pass fine.

So the issues seem to be specific to us using a custom request header with the new generation application load balancers and HTTP2.

Am I doing something wrong?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer on this post...

[AWS Application Load Balancer transforms all headers to lower case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39871250/aws-application-load-balancer-transforms-all-headers-to-lower-case)

It seems the headers come through from the ALB in lowercase. I needed to update my backend to support this

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to enable [Sticky sessions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html#sticky-sessions) in your loadbalancer.

They are needed to keep the session open liked to the same instance.

But, it's at application level the need of having to keep a session active, and not really useful in some kind of services, (*depending on the nature of your system, not really recommended*) as it provides performance reduction in REST like systems.